# Why is SSH safer than HTTPS on direct connections to a Git Repository with Credentials

Tags: ssh, git, https

Well, consider that the credentials are stored in a non secure manner somewhere on the file-system (default options on Ubuntu). There are quite a few sites which tell you that using SSH is more secure and should be used as-

> "With HTTPS, credentials are stored in an Un-encrypted file"

However this makes very little sense to me: with SSH you also have a simple file that stores the (private) key, so anyone who grabs that file can just as easily connect to the git repository.

And it's not like either of the files are more difficult to access: both are just stored on the local file-system mostly Un-encrypted (on Linux).

So what makes SSH more secure than HTTPS?

Comment: Im assuming that because of an SSH, it has direct access to the repository, rather than an open URL that can be accessed by anyone. So technically its jut a security thing in my eyes

Comment: It would help if you'd link to sites making such claims so that we have more information on their context. A quick Google for "With HTTPS, credentials are stored in an Un-encrypted file" turns up no results except for this question.

Comment: I would suggest to move this topic to Security SE

Comment: If you steal the SSH key, you only get access to the repositories on the account whereas if you steal the HTTPS credentials, you gain access to not only the repositories but also the account settings.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Some git repo systems allow you to specify a private key that you use (and store locally) in place of your account password. So if compromised, you only gain access to the repo, not the account. So it's nothing inherent to SSH over HTTPS itself, it's more an issue of the surrounding ecosystem.

Comment: @David That's called a PAT (Personal Access Token) and is used to authenticate without two factor. This still exposes account settings as it literally is just a replacement for the account password.

Comment: @KieranDevlin maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "account settings". I can't use the PAT to access the web portal for managing the account. Are you able to update these settings through the CLI itself?

Comment: @David Well it depends on the implementation (Different sites differ). For example GitHub PAT's have a permission system to only allow that token to be used for certain things but I believe even that lets you modify repository settings via the API if given access.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you were told that SSH is more secure than
HTTPS *in your particular case* (where we don't have all the details),
which may be absolutely correct, or whether you've been given this as
general advice. The analysis of SSH vs. HTTPS can be surprisingly
complex for those not well versed in security systems analysis, which
is why we tend to make broad statements such as "SSH is safer than
HTTPS": it's generally going to be true, even if it's not true in
every case. At any rate, here are some thoughts on the matter.

Since you mention storing credentials in a file, this answer assumes
that you're using public/private key authentication for both HTTPS and
SSH. Password authentication is significantly less secure in both
cases.

#### Local Credential Store

First, you're working with the assumption that the user's credential
stored on disk is not protected by a passphrase. This may or may not
be true, but if it were protected by a passphrase this would greatly
increase security.

In the case of SSH, the credential is more likely to be protected by a
passphrase because key agents are easier to use and more frequently
used with SSH. With SSH a key agent is almost invariably available
because `ssh-agent` or similar is part of almost every standard set of
SSH client tools. This also makes training to use the agent easy,
since training for the use of one tool in one particular way works
virtually everywhere.

Key agents for HTTPS systems are far more diverse, probably less
commonly installed and, even if available in a particular system,
it's less likely that someone would know that a particular one is
available and know how to use it.

#### Remote Agents

Second, SSH supports remote agent connections, allowing one to remove
the key material from the system on which you're doing the `git fetch`
which in many cases can lead to vastly improved security. This is best
described by an example of my most common workflow.

My laptop is a "personal" machine in the sense that I'm the only one
that has access to it. (It has full disk encryption and user accounts
only for me.) When I log in, I start a local `ssh-agent` and load my
key (also passphrase-protected) into that, with `ssh-askpass`
confirmation enabled via `ssh-add -c`.

When I SSH into the host on which I'm doing development, often shared
with others, I use `ssh -A` to enable agent forwarding. I then `git
fetch`, which starts an SSH session from the development host to the
server for the Git remote.

That SSH, when requested by the remote to authenticate, receives the
request and forwards it back to the agent on my laptop. I receive an
alert on my screen that my local agent has received a request to
authenticate, which I expect because I have just initiated an action
that would cause that, and so I approve the authentication. The SSH
process on the development host receives back the information it needs
to authenticate (valid for that particular session only), successfully
authenticates with the remote server, and my `git fetch` proceeds.

Note that this is considerably more secure because a) *the key was
never on the development server* and thus much, much less accessible
to attackers (they'd need to get to my private laptop), and b) I get
notified about requests for my key to be used, allowing me to detect
unexpected attempts to use the key. (Any user with root on the
development server is also able to forward authentication requests to
my laptop.) And I didn't have to type a passphrase every time, so
having passphrase-protected key file is much less hassle.